# Maximum number of tables in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How many tables possible to create in MS Sql database?

Answer (score 1):

Number of tables per database are limited by number of objects in a database. All objects in a database cannot exceed 2,147,483,647. Database objects include objects such as tables, views, stored procedures, user-defined functions, triggers, rules, defaults, and constraints.